# Why does "Access violation reading location" error occur in assembly?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, x86-64

Here is my *C++* code for finding max element in array:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

extern "C" int Max(int *i, int count);

    int main() {
        int i[10] = {1, 6, 7, 4, 8, 9, 6, 5 ,8 , 4};
        cout<< "Max " << Max(i ,10) << endl;

        _getch();
        return 0;
    }
```

Not completed, but I get the *Access violation reading location* error on `mov eax, [esi]` line.

My ASM code:

```
.code
Max proc

    mov esi,ecx
    mov ecx,edx
    mov eax, [esi]

    ret
Max endp
end
```

How can I solve this problem?

Edit: it's enough to know how can i get first element of the array.

Comment: Why do you use 32-bit registers for pointers on 64-bit environment?

Comment: Is it important? The code is working on the other pc. But in my computer, not. I am using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: If your _C_ code is 64-bit your assembler code routines need to be written for 64-bit as well.

Comment: Could you please rewrite the code ?

Comment: Also `esi` must be preserved, as it's callee-saved register according to standard calling convention. As it is, you just return the first number, I guess this is beginning of development. The 64 bit code could look like: `mov eax, [rcx]; ret`.

Comment: Yes this is beginning of development and i want to return the firs number of the array. Your solution is not working. I get the same error.

Comment: Are you sure you are compiling as 64 bit?

Comment: Yes, i am sure. I configurated visual studio.

Comment: When you used the debugger, what is the value of the `esi` register?

Comment: The use of 32 bit addresses in a 64 bit program is an error, but has a good chance of not being **THE** problem.  Similarly, failing to preserve esi is an error but likely not **THE** problem.  Most likely, the problem is that the 32/64 bit selection when assembling the asm code did not match the 32/64 bit selection when compiling the C++ code.  **Both** need to be 64-bit for the 64-bit parameter passing ABI to be usable.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas. I solved the problem when i see the value of registers. There was no esi register. There was rsi register instead of it. MikeCAT, Michael and JSF  also said true. I can't use 32 bit registers on 64-bit environment.

Comment: One big difference is that in 64-bit some values are passed in registers and if need be on the stack. This is different from 32-bit code. Incompatible calling conventions will cause problems.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When i check the values of registers in debug mode, `esi` wasn't there. There was `rsi` register instead of it. Then i rewrite the code like this;

```
mov rax,[rcx]
```

I deleted the other lines. Now, this is working like a charm.  I can get the first element of the array.

Thanks to @JSF.

Comment: "Working" does not mean correct.  That code is wrong because it fails to preserve rsi.  Some small change in the caller will change this same asm code from "working" to "causing its caller to crash later".

Comment: @JSF could you please write the correct code? I can't understand exactly.

Comment: Also you claimed that my solution of `mov eax, [rcx]` did not work ... when in fact that should, since all you do is move into `rsi`.... PS: you **can** use 32 bit registers in 64 bit mode too, just not for addressing (unless you know what you are doing).

Comment: Until you need something more complicated, the suggestion by Jester was correct.  Replace all three of those lines with `mov eax,[rcx]`.  When you think you tried Jester's suggestion, I'm sure you made some other mistake.

Comment: Using `rax` as you did, in place of Jester's suggestion of `eax` is a subtle mistake.  It won't bite you immediately, but is wrong and will eventually bite you.  An `int` is 32 bit and should use a 32-bit register.  A pointer should use a 64-bit register.

Comment: @JSF, OK. I changed my answer. Thanks for your explanations.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem I see is that your code changes esi and doesn't revert the changes to it, that is dangerous.
you should put a "push esi" at the start of your function, and add a "pop esi" at the end.

Comment: `push esi` isn't a valid 64-bit instruction.  But yes, from the question it does look like the args are in ECX and EDX, so we can assume the Windows x86-64 fastcall convention where RSI is call-preserved.  (Unlike x86-64 System V where it isn't.)  Anyway, that problem is secondary compared to truncating 64-bit pointers to 32-bit.